# Oracle SQL Convert to negative number

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to convert the following value 72.86- into the number -72.86?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you already selected a "correct answer" - which also already has two upvotes - but that is a very poor, amateur level solution.

The proper way to handle your input is to simply use the correct format model with the `to_number` function. For example:

```
select to_number('72.86-', '999.99mi') as my_number
from   dual;

 MY_NUMBER
----------
    -72.86
```

Notice the **mi** format model element - it means "minus sign, if present, is trailing". See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570

**EDIT**: Here is how the same can be used on a column with mixed format for positive numbers (notice the `fm` format modifier):

```
select str, to_number(str, 'fm999.99mi') as my_number
from
       (
         select '92.93-' as str from dual union all
         select null            from dual union all
         select '33.9+'         from dual union all
         select '6'             from dual union all
         select '0.00'          from dual
       )
;

STR     MY_NUMBER
------ ----------
92.93-     -92.93
                 
33.9+        33.9
6               6
0.00            0
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this for a whole column with positive and negative (minus trailing) numbers without having to use a case when?

Comment: @JaviTorre - see the EDIT I added at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Very robust answer!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the value is a string.  You can use:

```
(case when col like '%-'
      then - to_number(replace(col, '-', ''))
      else to_number(col)
 end)
```

Note that this will work for any character that might appear in the last position, including em-dashes, en-dashes, and characters from other character sets.

Comment: Very poor answer. Use the proper format model in `to_number`, don't cook up your own string manipulation to deal with the minus sign.